# How to split on several delimiters but keep those in between square brackets?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I am trying to split the following text string by dash, square brackets and colon delimiters but keep those in square brackets

Input:

```
10:100 - [10/09/21:12:23:22]
```

Desired output:

```
100, 10/09/21:12:23:22
```

My current code:

```
awk -F '[- ":]' '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With GNU `awk` you could try following code.

```
awk '
match($0,/:([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+-[[:space:]]+\[([^]]*)\]/,arr){
   print arr[1],arr[2]
}
' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using `sed`'s `s`(substitution operation) along with its capturing group capability try following:

```
sed -E 's/^[^:]*:([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+-[[:space:]]+\[([^]]*)\]/\1 \2/'  Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** Using any `awk` you could use following code. Using its `sub` and `gsub` operations on 1st and last fields.

```
awk '{sub(/.*:/,"",$1);gsub(/^\[|\]$/,"",$NF);print $1,$NF}' Input_file
```

***4th solution:*** With Perl's one-liner solution using a lazy match`.*?` one could try following using its substitution operation.

```
perl -pe 's/^.*?:([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+-[[:space:]]+\[([^]]*)\]/\1 \2/'  Input_file
```

Comment: sed worked best for me. How should I go about adding a comma between the 2 fields?

Comment: @yxx, sure, try like: `sed -E 's/^[^:]*:([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+-[[:space:]]+\[([^]]*)\]/\1,\2/'  Input_file` then. Which will add `,` between 2 matched values in output.

Comment: Works as well! If I have a longer string, say `10:100 - [10/09/21:12:23:22] /path/dir/` and would like to reorganise it to `10/09/21:12:23:22, 100, /path/dir/`, can I just call `\2,\1,\3`?

Comment: @yxx, No that will be a different regex. Use like: `sed -E 's/^[^:]*:([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+-[[:space:]]+\[([^]]*)\][[:space:]]+(.*)$/\1,\2,\3/'  Input_file` for that kind of output.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple of these patterns in the string and not regarding the order, you can make use of `awk`, match the patterns that you are interested in, and then remove the surrounding delimters.

In this case, you can match

```
\[[^][]+]|:[0-9]+
```

The pattern matches:

- `\[[^][]+]` Match from `[...]`
- `|` Or
- `:[0-9]+` Match `:` and 1+ digits

The part in gsub `[:\[]|\]$` matches either `:` `[`  at the start of the string, or match `]` at the end of the string, and will replace that with an empty string.

```
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/\[[^][]+]|:[0-9]+/)){
    v = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    gsub(/^[:\[]|\]$/, "", v)
    print v
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
' file
```

Output

```
100
10/09/21:12:23:22
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming no empty lines within input data :

```
echo '10:100 - [10/09/21:12:23:22]' |
```

> ```
>    nawk 'sub("^[^:]*:",_, $!--NF)' FS='[ -]*[][]' OFS=', '
> or
>    gawk 'NF -= sub("^[^:]*:",_)' FS='[ -]*[][]' OFS=', '
> or 
>    mawk 'NF -= sub("^[^:]*:",_)' FS='[][ -]+' OFS=', '
> ```

```
100, 10/09/21:12:23:22
```